# Advice for advanced performance tuning - Beyond basic indexing

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure, sqlperformance

## Summary

I'm planning on storing a list of license plates in a SQL Azure database with the following schema:

## Schema

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[events](
    [id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [dateTimeCreated] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [registration] [varchar](14) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[events] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_events_dateTimeCreated]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [dateTimeCreated]
GO
```

I can only think of running the following one query: 
- Search for registration within a given date/time range

So far I can only think of creating a non-clustered index agaisnt dateTimeCreated and registration

## Question

There may end up being 10's of millions of rows. 
* What options (azure specific or not) are there for improving performance when the row count finally does increase greatly? 
* Are there any guides on how the query performance will de-grade for a given number of rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely create a **clustered** index for `dateTimeCreated`. The `registration` column should also be indexed but whether (and how) it should be indexed depends on the data: Will your `registration` have some sequnce to them or will they be random?

**Key idea behind [Clustered Indexes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190457.aspx):**

> The only time the data rows in a table are stored in sorted order is
>   when the table contains a clustered index.

This means that when you do a search on a column that is clustered and the values have some order-able semantics (your `dateTimeCreated` column) your likelyhood of fetching the right data goes up significantly. (SQL Server does not have to fetch - as many - table pages to gather the necessary data.)

Also: ([MSDN documentation link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee336245.aspx#cir))

> Microsoft Azure SQL Database does not support tables without clustered
>   indexes. A table must have a clustered index. If a table is created
>   without a clustered constraint, a clustered index must be created
>   before an insert operation is allowed on the table.

Answer (score 0):

I would make ID a PK (and clustered index)

And why bigint?
int goes up to 4 billion (8 billion if you use the negative)
Not just less disc space but you have more records cached in the same amount of memory.

count(*) will be order n
twice as many records will take twice as long to count

As for the other columns create an index if you are going to search or sort on them.

Comment: I agree with your bigint suggestion but... You're suggesting a clustered index on a pkey ID column just to speed up `count` operations? That's the SQL Server default and not at all useful in this case. The OP (@DavidHawkins) is clearly asking about search performance on the `dateTimeCreated` and `registration` columns. Those columns should be clustered to reduce page fetches significantly thereby improving performance.

Comment: @PaulSasik OK that is your opinion and your answer.  I will use an iden as the PK pretty much every time (or I will not even have an iden).  I suspect the purpose is for FK.  For one on an insert I can get back the value of the iden for use in populating FK tables.   Getting back the value of the datetime is not as easy.  And getdate() is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: @Blam - The `id` column should certainly be indexed for foreign key look ups though we don't see the rest of the structure of the OP's database and exactly how this table will relate to others. The primary concern is performance for a particular search query filtered by datetime. No, it is not guaranteed to be unique but that's ok. Each row will be unique if such a constraint is put on the datetime and registration coumns. The clustered index will simply arrange the data "physically" on disc and in memory so that fetches with a datetime filter are more performant.

Comment: @PaulSasik I don't have any questions.  I know what clustered index is and how it works.  That is my answer.  You have your answer.   As I said if iden is not used as FK then I would not have one.